# SQL Server - How to set the default field type?

Tags: sql-server

I create a table from a text file as follows:

```
SELECT * 
INTO new_table
FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL', 
    'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)};
Extended Properties="text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"'
    ,'select * from C:\text_file.txt')
```

It is working but all columns are created with datatype `varchar(255)`. I would like to switch to `nvarchar(max)`.

**Question**: is it possible to set the default type to `nvarchar(max)`? In SQL Server settings or somewhere else?

Important: all the point is not to define the column names as they may vary. So I cannot do `SELECT CAST(Column1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))...`

Comment: `SELECT CAST(Column1 AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Column1Name, CAST(Column2 AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Column2Name ... INTO new_table`

Comment: All the point is not to define the column names as they may vary...

Comment: Are you having trouble with data truncation, that is necessitating the need for `NVARCHAR(MAX)` or is this just a preference?

Comment: Yes it is to avoid data truncation in case I have very long strings (ie. comments...)

Comment: Interesting question.  I suppose you could initially create `new_table` with no rows (using a WHERE 1 = 2 clause).  Then you could iterate over the columns (via dynamic t-sql) and ALTER the VARCHAR(255) columns to VARCHAR(MAX). Then lastly insert into the table via OPENROWSET.  This seems overly complicated for what you're trying to accomplish, though.

Comment: Indeed it seems very complicated. I actually I thought this could be configured at server level in some properties...

Comment: In that `Extended Properties` part... is `IMEX` recognized?  I think it worked with the older jet engine...So something like `...text;IMEX=0;HDR=YES;FMT=...`.  If it accepts that syntax, I think the Access/Excel driver will read all rows of your spreadsheet to determine the size of VARCHAR columns.

Comment: It's not a server level thing it's actually the the driver `{Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}` coming up with what it thinks are the data types then creating the table. There is no default data type they are created explicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- create temp table for column list

```
SELECT top 1 * INTO #dt
FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL', 
    'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)};
Extended Properties="text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"'
    ,'select * from C:\text_file.txt')
```

2- create sql script for new table and add all columns with nvarchar(max)

```
declare @Rows int = 1
declare @colName nvarchar(150)
declare @Id int = 0
declare @MySql  nvarchar(max)


set @MySql = 'CREATE TABLE new_table ( '

WHILE @Rows>0
BEGIN

    SELECT top 1  @Id = ORDINAL_POSITION, @colName =COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'#dt' and ORDINAL_POSITION >@Id

    set @Rows =@@RowCount
    if @Rows>0
    begin
        set @MySql = @MySql +   @colName     + ' nvarchar(max) ,'
    end

END

set @MySql = substring(@MySql,0,(len(@MySql)-1)) +')'
exec (@MySql)
```

3- run your insert script and fill data to your real table

```
SELECT * INTO new_table
FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL', 
    'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)};
Extended Properties="text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"'
    ,'select * from C:\text_file.txt')
```